# Upload a file form jsp to amazonS3

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-s3, liferay, liferay-6

I want to upload a file from a jsp page using AWS SDK to amazon-s3. But for some reason i cannot send the file in my java class. Can  someone explain me how i should do the file passing to the class.

More info:

Let`s say that I have myPage.jsp page and inside I have a form that allows the user to chose a file from his computer:

```
    <input type="file" name="myFile" /> Please chose a file to upload
```

and I have upload.java file

```
    public void UploadDocument(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws   
    IOException, PortletException, AmazonClientException, AmazonServiceException{

        File upFile = new File(actionRequest.getParameter("myFile");
                ...
        //From fere on i make my amazon connection and i ma trying to pass the file
}
```

but i cannot read the file like that it returns null.

I am using Amazon AWS SDK, Liferay portlets SDK, java and jsp

I hope this is enough information

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tyr this code

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("myFile");
```

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: it still gives me null i have no idea why. Thanks for trying!

Comment: <form action="<%=uploadFile %>"  enctype="multipart/form-    data">Upload file in your folder <input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit" value="UPLOAD"></form>

Comment: and from here it goes in the java method

Comment: you need to get using this "uploadRequest.getFileName("file");" try this one

Comment: let me know if u still have problem

Comment: UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
  String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("file");
  File submissionFile = uploadRequest.getFile("file");
   
  String accessKey = "1234567890";
  String secretKey = "1234567890";
 
  AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
  AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials); 
   
  client.putObject("pm-portal-test", cid+"/"+sourceFileName, submissionFile);